# Compare a list/array to a dataframe column?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a list or array contains values[apple,items] and i want a resultant df with where column('c') has the same list/array values.

Suppose in below eg: A can be a list/array/str and resultant df is based on the values in A compared with df 'c' column

eg:

```
   A = [apple,items]
```

df

```
                        a         b        c

                0       10        13      items

                1       9         12      testcase

                2       8         11      apple

                3       7         10      apple

                4       6         9       test

                5       5         8       items
```

Final df

```
                        a         b        c

                0       10        13      items

                1       8         11      apple

                2       7         10      apple

                3       5         8       items
```

I tried with boolean indexing but couldn't succeced

Comment: [pandas series.isin()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.isin.html)

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to work it out with this:

```
df['Status'] = df['c'].isin(A)
```

This should add a column named Status that will be True when the row for column C is apple or items, False otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

You want to use [`pd.Series.isin()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.isin.html) and pass the results as a boolean mask to filter your original dataframe:

```
A = ['apples','items']

df_final = df[df['c'].isin(A)]
```

Answer (score 1):

You create a boolean:

```
selection = df['c'].isin(A)
```

and then get your final df from it:

```
Final_df = df[selection]
```